# php create Persian/Arabic search engine friendly urls (unicode)

Tags: php, seo, preg-replace

I try to make search engine firendly urls are included Persian or Arabic characters .
In url `SPACES` and `symbols` must replace with `-` character.

**My Example input is** : `عنوان آزمایشی - Test Title`

I try to do it with my Function :

```
$title = trim(ereg_replace(' +', ' ', preg_replace("/[^اآبپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهیa-zA-Z0-9\s]/", '', strtolower($title))));
```

**But give a result** : `عنوان-آزما�ش�-test-title`

**Result must be** : `عنوان-آزمایشی---Test-Title` *(for example)*

Where's the problem ? *I know Persian words are on Unicode but don't know how to pass it !*

EDIT : problem like character `ی` or `یـ` always turn into `�` , but I try to find a safer way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Thanks John , but Question about is How spaces or symbols can removed and replaced with dash when string included with unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find a solution on Internet but find the solution myself on simplest way :

```
preg_replace('/&([^#])(?![a-z]{1,8};)/i', '&#038;$1', $title);
```

Result is pretty good .

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `strtolower` is not multibyte-capable.

Instead, consider [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.mb-strtolower.php) which handles multi-byte UTF characters.